# Search for comprehensive term for plants with heat generation with heat storage and operating states

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heating-systems, combustion, heat-exchanger

My master thesis deals with systems with several operating states that generate heat and store it in a heat storage. Thereby I analyze combined heat and power plants with combustion engines, but also heat pumps.

Now I am looking for a comprehensive term for such systems in my thesis and in the title. The term "heat generators" seems a bit too simplified to me.

Are there any more specific alternatives for a comprehensive term that might also point to the heat storage tank and the limited number of operating states?

Comment: What about solar water heating and inter-seasonal storage some excellent material about that...

Comment: Seems like "thermal storage" would be the key point to differentiate the plants you're looking for from others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm still thinking. My colleague uses the term 'systems with decoupled demand' - what do you think of that?